# Flat file event calendar in PHP

Tags: php, events, file, calendar, flat

I need to make a flat file PHP calendar that an admin would be able to edit, delete, and make new events. Does anyone know where I could find something like this, like maybe a tutorial? I can't download one that would need a licence for selling, by the way.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't use a pre-made one, but are asking where you can find one?

Comment: so, your question has nothjing to do with programming but it's about looking for free software, right?

Comment: Pretty much. I couldn't really find anything, so I thought maybe somebody on stackoverflow might know something like that.

Comment: there is nothing particular in calendars. it's just regular web application, much like any other. you can either learn PHP and write your own or download some free application, there are plenty of open-source ones. however, last option is offtopic here, stackoverflow is for programming, not code search. you could ask some google lessons on the superuser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) seems to be a very nice and featured calendar. It requires jQuery. You will surely need some ajax in your application background to associate events with your PHP models. I've used it and it fit our requirements very well.

Answer (score 1):

I´m not sure what you mean by finding it but not being able to download it, but if you get `Pro PHP and jQuery` you'll be making one step by step. Just replace the db stuff with file stuff.